# Bar Chart-Different Colours bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to create a bar chart for the public dataset Bellabeat. My code is the following:

```
ggplot(data=daily_activity_summary)+
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x=ActivityDateWeekly, y=Average_Total_Steps,fill=ActivityDateWeekly))
```

The issue is that each bar has different shades of the same color (i.e. light blue, dark blue etc). However ,I want each column to have a different color (e.g red ,blue etc). Could someone help with this issue please?
Thanks
Panos

I used ggplot package and I expected each bar has different color (i.e. red,blue etc) but it was shown a bar chart with different shades of the same color (i.e. blue)

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because R interprets you variable as continuous and not a factor. If you specify that it's a factor then you will get the colors you need. See the example below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#not what you want
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,color = vs)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
# what you want
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp,color = factor(vs))) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>